# Error while launching app GWT 2.6.1. and GXT 3.1.0

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

Saw similar compile time issues for different versions of of GWt and GXt,
but no solution found yet.

getting error like

> Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'
>           Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.data.Data'
>              Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.core.Core'
>                 [ERROR] The value ie6 was not previously defined.
>                 [ERROR] Line 96: Unexpected exception while processing element 'set-property'

tried solutions from [GWT 2.6 with GXT-3.0.1 error in compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517007/gwt-2-6-with-gxt-3-0-1-error-in-compile?rq=1) but not helping..

Please give your inputs

Comment: Loading modules
   com.app.ApplicationShellModule
      Loading inherited module 'com.app.ApplicationShellModule'
         Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'
            Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.data.Data'
               Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.core.Core'
                  [ERROR] The value ie6 was not previously defined.
                  [ERROR] Line 96: Unexpected exception while processing element 'set-property'

Comment: It looks like you have some older code in your project. Have tried to clean the project?

Comment: Yes,  I tried cleanup, mvn build is successful.! even added extend-property for ie6. seems issue like this https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?282179&langid=1 . Could suggest how to make dependenc/ classpath cleanup for mvn repo

Comment: Issue is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32451248/not-able-to-run-gxt-3-1-1-application-after-upgrading-from-3-0-0